# Shaping Julia multidimensional arrays

Tags: julia

I am new to Julia and am working with creating a properly shaped multidimensional array.

```
function get_deets(curric)
    curric = curric.metrics
    return ["" curric["complexity"][1] curric["blocking factor"][1] curric["delay factor"][1]] 
end

function compare_currics(currics...)
    headers = [" ", "Complexity", "Blocking Factor", "Delay Factor"]
    data = [get_deets(curric) for curric in currics]
     return pretty_table(data, headers)
end
```

The data I am getting back is:

```
3-element Array{Array{Any,2},1}:
 ["" 393.0 184 209.0]
 ["" 361.0 164 197.0]
 ["" 363.0 165 198.0]
```

However, I need something that looks like this:

```
3×4 Array{Any,2}:
 ""  393.0  184  209.0
 ""  361.0  164  197.0
 ""  363.0  165  198.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would replace the comprehension `[get_deets(curric) for curric in currics]` with a reduction.

For example:

```
using Random

function getdeets(curric)
    # random "deets", as a 1-D Vector
    return [randstring(4), rand(), 10rand(), 100rand()]
end

function getdata(currics)
    # All 1-D vectors are concatenated horizontally, to produce a
    # 2-D matrix with "deets" as columns (efficient since Julia matrices
    # are stored in column major order)
    data = reduce(hcat, getdeets(curric) for curric in currics)
    return data
end
```

With this, you get a slightly different structure than what you want: it is transposed, but that should be more efficient overall

```
julia> getdata(1:3)
4×3 Array{Any,2}:
   "B2Mq"     "S0hO"      "6KCn"
  0.291359   0.00046518  0.905285
  4.03026    0.612037    8.6458
 35.3133    79.3744      6.49379
```

If you want your tabular data to be presented in the same way as your question, this solution can easily be adapted:

```
function getdeets(curric)
    # random "deets", as a row matrix
    return [randstring(4) rand() 10rand() 100rand()]
end

function getdata(currics)
    # All rows are concatenated vertically, to produce a
    # 2-D matrix
    data = reduce(vcat, getdeets(curric) for curric in currics)
    return data
end
```

This produces:

```
julia> getdata(1:3)
3×4 Array{Any,2}:
 "eU7p"  0.563626  0.282499  52.1877
 "3pIw"  0.646435  8.16608   27.534
 "AI6z"  0.86198   0.235428  25.7382
```

Comment: Thanks so much, the latter version is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like for the stuff you want to do you need a `DataFrame` rather than an `Array`.
Look at the sample Julia session below:

```
julia> using DataFrames, Random

julia> df = DataFrame(_=randstring(4), Complexity=rand(4), Blocking_Factor=rand(4), Delay_Factor=rand(4))
4×4 DataFrame
│ Row │ _      │ Complexity │ Blocking_Factor │ Delay_Factor │
│     │ String │ Float64    │ Float64         │ Float64      │
├─────┼────────┼────────────┼─────────────────┼──────────────┤
│ 1   │ S6vT   │ 0.817189   │ 0.00723053      │ 0.358754     │
│ 2   │ S6vT   │ 0.569289   │ 0.978932        │ 0.385238     │
│ 3   │ S6vT   │ 0.990195   │ 0.232987        │ 0.434745     │
│ 4   │ S6vT   │ 0.59623    │ 0.113731        │ 0.871375     │

julia> Matrix(df[!,2:end])
4×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.817189  0.00723053  0.358754
 0.569289  0.978932    0.385238
 0.990195  0.232987    0.434745
 0.59623   0.113731    0.871375
```

Note that in the last part we have converted the numerical part of the data into an `Array` (I assume you need an `Array` at some point). Note that this `Array` is containing only `Float64` elements. In practice this means that no boxing will occur when storing values and any operation on such `Array` will be an order of magnitude faster. To illustrate the point have a look at the code below (I copy the data from `df` into two almost identical `Array`s).

```
julia> m = Matrix(df[!,2:end])
4×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.817189  0.00723053  0.358754
 0.569289  0.978932    0.385238
 0.990195  0.232987    0.434745
 0.59623   0.113731    0.871375

julia> m2 = Matrix{Any}(df[!,2:end])
4×3 Array{Any,2}:
 0.817189  0.00723053  0.358754
 0.569289  0.978932    0.385238
 0.990195  0.232987    0.434745
 0.59623   0.113731    0.871375

julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> @btime mean($m)
  5.099 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
0.5296580253263143

julia> @btime mean($m2)
  203.103 ns (12 allocations: 192 bytes)
0.5296580253263143
```